# tk: notebook automatically activate next tab after current tab job done

Tags: tabs, widget, tk-toolkit

I design the GUI with multiple tabs format with ttk::notebook widget. 
And different tab contains independent functions in certain flow. 
I want to switch to certain tab automatically after functions in current tab finished. 
Is there some good method to activate certain tab with command instead of manually operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking this up the yesterday.
Do:

```
  $notebookwindow select <tabid>
```

There are a lot of different ways to specify the tabid.  Using integer numbers is easiest probably.

The manual page: [enter link description here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm)